# eclipse enide 2015 REST client header

Tags: xml, eclipse, rest, header, enide

I am using Enide 2015 "RestClient Tool" within Eclipse Mars and although I have included my header information in the following format, my header is not recognized and I get a 500 error.

```
Authorization: Basic gus8gsiugs897g8u48=
Context-type: application/xml
```

I have also tried:

```
"Authorization","Basic gus8gsiugs897g8u48="
"Context-type","application/xml"
```

and

```
Authorization="Basic gus8gsiugs897g8u48="
Context-type="application/xml"
```

The Headers multi-line text box allows for one Header entry per line.

In fact, when I send the REST message, the response within the Request Detail window, a mirror of the actual request, does not include my header. It seems as if it used its own header.

I know this is related to the Authentication portion of the header because it works in Postman. The XML is well-formed and is schema-compliant.  I am sure it is something simple but I can find nothing on their web site or anywhere else to me get past this one hurdle.

Comment: I think you mean Content-type vs Context-type, in which case this question should probably be closed as a simply typo.

Comment: Thank you.  I made the change from "Context" to "Content" and received the same response.  I'll keep trying.